# Cython c++ example fails to recognize c++, why?

Tags: c++, python, cython

I'm attempting to build to the example for 'using c++ in cython' at [the Cython C++ page](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html), but setup appears not to recognize the language, c++.

The files, taken from that same page are:

**Rectangle.cpp**

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

using namespace shapes;

Rectangle::Rectangle(int X0, int Y0, int X1, int Y1){
    x0 = X0;
    y0 = Y0;
    x1 = X1;
    y1 = Y1;
}

Rectangle::~Rectangle() {}

int Rectangle::getLength() {
    return (x1 - x0);
}

int Rectangle::getHeight() {
    return (y1 - y0);
} 

int Rectangle::getArea() {
    return (x1 - x0) * (y1 - y0);
}

void Rectangle::move(int dx, int dy) {
    x0 += dx;
    y0 += dy;
    x1 += dx;
    y1 += dy;
}
```

---

**Rectangle.h:**

```
namespace shapes {
    class Rectangle {
    public:
    int x0, y0, x1, y1;
    Rectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
    ~Rectangle();
    int getLength();
    int getHeight();
    int getArea();
    void move(int dx, int dy);
    };
 }
```

---

**rectangle.pyx**

```
cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
cdef cppclass Rectangle:
    Rectangle(int, int, int, int)
    int x0, y0, x1, y1
    int getLength()
    int getHeight()
    int getArea()
    void move(int, int)

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle *thisptr      # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.thisptr = new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def getLength(self):
        return self.thisptr.getLength()
    def getHeight(self):
        return self.thisptr.getHeight()
    def getArea(self):
        return self.thisptr.getArea()
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.thisptr.move(dx, dy)
```

---

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
       "rectangle.pyx",            # our Cython source
       sources=["Rectangle.cpp"],  # additional source file(s)
       language="c++",             # generate C++ code
      ))
```

---

I attempt to build this with:

```
python setup.py --build_ext --inplace
```

But this fails, with the error "Operation only allowed in c++" suggesting that the language="c++" option is not being passed correctly.

```
cython rectangle.pyx --cplus
```

does produce a c++ file, but I was hoping to be able to get the setup.py method to work.

The entire error text is:

```
Cythonizing rectangle.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        void move(int, int)

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle *thisptr      # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.thisptr = new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

rectangle.pyx:13:27: Operation only allowed in c++

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle *thisptr      # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.thisptr = new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

rectangle.pyx:15:8: Operation only allowed in c++
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    language="c++",             # generate C++ code
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.19.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8intel.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 753, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args[1:])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.19.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8intel.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 820, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: rectangle.pyx
```

Comment: As a side note, it's really not a good idea to call one file `Rectangle.cpp`, and then name another file so it will compile to `rectangle.cpp`. I don't think that's your problem here, but it definitely makes things more confusing, and at least creates a potential for problems (especially if you ever want to work on Windows).

Comment: I agree, but I took these files exactly word for word from the Cython c++ tutorial, figuring that they would be guaranteed to be correct.  I'm just at the stage of figuring out how to compile Cython.

Comment: No, the Cython C++ tutorial has `rect.pyx`, not `rectangle.pyx`, for exactly this reason. Also, while we're at it, your Cython module has an IndentationError in it (cppclass needs to be indented under the extern); can I assume your real code doesn't?

Comment: Also, `python setup.py --build_ext --inplace` isn't a valid build line. I think you wanted `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, with `build_ext` as a setup command rather than an option.

Comment: Finally, the sample sets the language and sources in comments at the top of `rect.pyx`, while your code doesn't do that. And that one seems likely to be your actual problem, unlike all the other things above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following the example exactly, on a very similar system to yours, everything works fine for me.

But, along with a few other differences (an IndentationError, naming the file `rectangle.pyx` instead of `rect.pyx`, …) which turned out not to be relevant to this problem, you also left off this at the top of your Cython file:

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = Rectangle.cpp
```

And if I leave that off, I get the same error.