# Syntax Error in Cython Example

Tags: c++, python, cython

I am trying to build a Cython Example at [this page](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#create-cython-wrapper-class).

I know my post is very similar to one other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154361/cython-c-example-fails-to-recognize-c-why). However, I generated totally different error messages.

Here are my code:

**Rectangle.cpp**

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

using namespace shapes;

Rectangle::Rectangle(int X0, int Y0, int X1, int Y1){
    x0 = X0;
    y0 = Y0;
    x1 = X1;
    y1 = Y1;
}

Rectangle::~Rectangle() {}

int Rectangle::getLength() {
    return (x1 - x0);
}

int Rectangle::getHeight() {
    return (y1 - y0);
} 

int Rectangle::getArea() {
    return (x1 - x0) * (y1 - y0);
}

void Rectangle::move(int dx, int dy) {
    x0 += dx;
    y0 += dy;
    x1 += dx;
    y1 += dy;
}
```

**Rectangle.h**

```
namespace shapes {
    class Rectangle {
    public:
    int x0, y0, x1, y1;
    Rectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
    ~Rectangle();
    int getLength();
    int getHeight();
    int getArea();
    void move(int dx, int dy);
    };
 }
```

**rectangle.pyx**

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = Rectangle.cpp

cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        Rectangle(int, int, int, int)
        int x0, y0, x1, y1
        int getLength()
        int getHeight()
        int getArea()
        void move(int, int)

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle *thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.thisptr = new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def getLength(self):
        return self.thisptr.getLength()
    def getHeight(self):
        return self.thisptr.getHeight()
    def getArea(self):
        return self.thisptr.getArea()
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.thisptr.move(dx, dy)
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
       "rectangle.pyx",            # our Cython source
       sources=["Rectangle.cpp"],  # additional source file(s)
       language="c++",             # generate C++ code
      ))
```

I have to admit that I had the same mistake that missing following lines in `rectangle.pyx` at the first place.

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = Rectangle.cpp
```

After read through the post at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154361/cython-c-example-fails-to-recognize-c-why), I realized it and fixed it.

However, when I use following statement to compile the C++ class,

```
python rectangle.pyx
```

I had following error message:

```
File "rectangle.pyx", line 4
    cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why this error pops up? May I know how to fix it?

Many thanks. :)

===================================================

PS: When I try to run `setup.py`, I had a `g++` error:

I ran:

```
python setup.py build_ext
```

and the `g++` error is

```
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: `python rectangle.pyx` python has no-idea of what a `.pyx` file is. You first have to build the extension, and afterwards to import it into a python program. If the building fails you should post the *whole* output you get. not just a single line. You may also try to build calling cython directly(see [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-from-the-command-line)). [I suggest to read that link, since it also explains how to generate an HTML file that can tell you where the cython code can be optimized]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Bakuriu 's advice, I found following procedure works:

suppose you are using a command prompt

1. cd to the directory that contains the `.pyx` and `setup` files.
2. using Cython to build extension, such as

   `Cython -a rect.pyx --cplus`
3. using Python to setup up the extension, such as

   `Python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

When using the extension, you can:

1. append the directory of .pyd file to your system path

   `import sys`

   `sys.path.append("C:\\yourDirectory")`
2. using the extension as you like :)

   `import Rectangle`

   `r = Rectangle.PyRectangle(1,2,3,4)`